# How to get specific css styled element from the entire node

Tags: javascript, html, css, mutation-observers

I am using MutationObserver to listen for any element added in the dom. After the element(s) is added, I want to check whether the element(s) had the computer style cursor to be pointer or not. But I am not sure how to approach this problem as it returns the parent node added in the dom, it didn't query each child of the parent node :-

```js
function myfunc() {
    const ele = document.createElement('div')
  ele.innerHTML = `<span><a>I am added</a></span><h2><a>I am two</a></h2>`
  
  document.body.appendChild(ele)
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationsList => {
  mutationsList.forEach(mutation => {
    // Check if nodes were added
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      // Iterate over added nodes
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(addedNode => {
        // Check if added node is an element and not a script
        if (
          addedNode.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&
          addedNode.tagName !== 'SCRIPT'
        ) {

          const child = addedNode.childNodes;
          if(child.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
              console.log(child[i])
                if(window.getComputedStyle(child[i]).cursor === 'pointer') {
                console.log('This')
              }
                else {
                    console.log('No It didn')
                }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myfunc()">
Add to DOM
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd start by using a dedicated container div to push elements into instead of the body of the document.

Next you dont have to work with child list and instead (since you only add elements) can simply get the latest element added to the container (or body). Afterwards you get all anchor elements of that element by using lastElementChild. Now iterate over each anchor tag and compare the computed style with what you want.

```js
function myfunc() {
  const ele = document.createElement('div');
  ele.innerHTML = `<span><a>I am added</a></span><h2><a>I am two</a></h2>`;
  const elem = document.getElementById("container");
  elem.appendChild(ele);
  i++;
}

let i = 0; //specify a value to distinguish each span
const targetNode = document.getElementById("container");
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
      const container = document.getElementById("container");
      let lastElement = container.lastElementChild;
      var a = lastElement.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        var elem = a[j];
        const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(elem).cursor;
        if(compStyles == 'pointer')
        {
          console.log("Works!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myfunc()">
Add to DOM
</button>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am basically developing an extension and that extension injects scripts into the user's dom. So I want to listen to the user's dom and then act accordingly. I can't getElements by name or something because a cursor pointer could be set to anything